# Set alpha value for only a part of an UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have put 2 UIImageViews on top of each other. The bottom one is just a  green image and the top one is blue. On top of that I have a UIView. The idea is to be able to drag the UIView up and down, and instead of only seeing the green colour, the UIView will show the bottom image, the blue colour, inside its rectangle.

[image: This is what it looks like]

I have added a Pan Gesture Recogniser to the UIView so i can drag it up and down, which works just fine. I have tried to search the internet to find out how I can change the alpha of the green image ONLY inside the UIView rectangle, so that it will look like a window, but without any luck. This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var windowViewOrigin: CGPoint!

@IBOutlet weak var topImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var windowView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addPanGesture(view: windowView)
    windowViewOrigin = windowView.frame.origin
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func addPanGesture(view: UIView){
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let window = sender.view!
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

    switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed :
        windowView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*0.5, y: window.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        break
    case .ended:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.topImageView.alpha = 0.0
        }
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
}
```

I hope someone can help me in the right direction, I have no idea how to move on from this point.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a CAShapeLayer as a mask on your top image view's layer.

(In iOS views are actually thin wrappers around Core Animation Layers, that do the actual drawing.

You can create a CAShapeLayer that defines a shape and install it as the mask layer of your image view's layer. Then the opaque parts of the mask cause your image view to be visible, but transparent parts of the mask hide those parts of the mask. You can shift the origin of the mask in response to a pan gesture to shift the masked area around.

I suggest searching on CAShapeLayer and mask. There are quite a few tutorials online. (I haven't messed with shape layers and masks in a while, and when I did it was in Objective-C. I don't think I have any Swift code lying around that I can share.)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: make two green ImageViews that will be displayed to the top and to the bottom of your middle transparent windowView and change positions/heights of these two views according to position of your windowView. So, green views will be never displayed under windowView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That won't work for me though. I'm working on a project where I have to simulate an x-ray. I only choose colours just to make it easy to differentiate between the two imageViews. 
Imagine the UIView as a window to look past the green image into the blue one. Or the top image a man, and the blue image the insides of the same man, if that makes sense. That's what Im trying to do